# Reference XML mappings for Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

The following code worked in version 3.5.1404, but is no longer working in version 5.0.1. Have the latest references via NuGet:

in web.config I have:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration;
using Unity;

namespace ACME.Core
{
    public static class UnityCommon
    {
        static IUnityContainer _container;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the Common Unity Container from memory, reloads if not loaded first
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="forceRefresh">Forces the container to be reloaded in memory</param>
        /// <returns>IUnityContainer</returns>
        public static IUnityContainer GetContainer(bool forceRefresh = false)
        {
            if (_container == null || forceRefresh)
            {
                _container = new UnityContainer();
                _container.LoadConfiguration("Default"));
            }

            return _container;
        }
    }
}
```

This references XML mappings in web.config such as:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <assembly name="ACME.Core" />
    <namespace name="ACME.Core.DTO" />

    <container name="Default">
      <register type="IStatusRepository" mapTo="StatusRepository" />
      <register type="INoteRepository" mapTo="NoteRepository" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

Error:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException occurred
>   HResult=0x80131902 Message=An error occurred creating the
>   configuration section handler for unity: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Source=Unity.Configuration StackTrace: at
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityContainerExtensions.LoadConfiguration(IUnityContainer
>   container, String containerName)
>
> at
>   System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost
>   host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError) at
>   System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord
>   configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord) at
>   System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord
>   configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord) at
>   System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord
>   factoryRecord) at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String
>   configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)

Do I need to call the XML configuration differently?

BTW, I tried it with just _container.LoadConfiguration(); and received the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out with help from contributor at Github (ENikS).

I was using the old namespace issue:

```
<section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
```

But once I used the new one you provided it worked:

```
<section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Unity.Configuration"/>
```